# Trait Bound is not satisfied for Result<(), Box<(dyn SomeTrait + 'static)>>

Tags: rust, traits, abstraction, dynamic-dispatch

```rust
use once_cell::sync::OnceCell;

pub trait SomeTrait {}
pub struct Impl1 {}

impl SomeTrait for Impl1 {}

pub static GLOBAL_THING: OnceCell<Box<dyn SomeTrait>> = OnceCell::new();

pub fn main() {
    GLOBAL_THING.set(Box::new(Impl1 {})).unwrap();
}
```

I'm getting this error and not sure how to interpret it's meaning or fix it.

```
error[E0599]: the method `unwrap` exists for enum `Result<(), Box<(dyn SomeTrait + 'static)>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:11:42
    |
11  |       GLOBAL_THING.set(Box::new(Impl1 {})).unwrap();
    |                                            ^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Result<(), Box<(dyn SomeTrait + 'static)>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `Box<dyn SomeTrait>: Debug`
```

An easy workaround is to just do `if let Err() = GLOBAL_THING.set() {panic!(...)}` instead of using `unwrap()`, but I'd like to understand what's going on here and fix if possible.

Answer (score 6):

If you take a look at the [`unwrap` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) documentation you'll see that it's not defined for all `Result`s, but only ones where `E: Debug`:

```
impl<T, E> Result<T, E>
where
    E: Debug, 
{
    pub fn unwrap(self) -> T;
}
```

It needs the error type `E` to implement `Debug` so that the error can be printed if unwrapping fails.

The error message shows that the result type is `Result<(), Box<(dyn SomeTrait + 'static)>>`, so `E = Box<(dyn SomeTrait + 'static)>`. You can make this error type debuggable by having `SomeTrait: Debug`, which requires that any type that implements `SomeTrait` must also implement `Debug`.

```rust
pub trait SomeTrait: Debug {}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Impl1 {}
```

Once you do this you'll hit the next error:

```
error[E0277]: `dyn SomeTrait` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:11:1
   |
11 | pub static GLOBAL_THING: OnceCell<Box<dyn SomeTrait>> = OnceCell::new();
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `dyn SomeTrait` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `dyn SomeTrait`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Sync` for `Unique<dyn SomeTrait>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Box<dyn SomeTrait>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Sync` for `once_cell::imp::OnceCell<Box<dyn SomeTrait>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `once_cell::sync::OnceCell<Box<dyn SomeTrait>>`
   = note: shared static variables must have a type that implements `Sync`
```

To fix this you'll also want to make the boxed trait object `Send + Sync` so that it can be shared across threads.

```rust
pub static GLOBAL_THING: OnceCell<Box<dyn SomeTrait + Send + Sync>> = OnceCell::new();
```

You can see the final result on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4e3447e624924357bb015c33d978dec4).

Comment: Thanks, John!

In case you're curious, the actual Trait is called TimestampGenerator and it's just a wrapper for the system timestamp, but I use a MockTimestampGenerator during testing which I can manually advance(1000).

I had tried deriving Debug on the structs, but didn't realize I need : Debug on the trait. I already had Send + Sync from when this was sorta working with lazy_static.

Comment: Anyway, you rock. Thanks.